# javascript currency format with decimal recognition

Tags: javascript, acrobat

i stumbled across your this site while looking for a solution for my problem.
I m new to javascript but already starting to love it. This one problem i can´t solve on my own yet.
Here s the deal:

I need the have a script for Acrobat that tells my field that:
 
1. It´s a currency field always ending with (blank)€
 
2. The user needs to be able to enter prices with 2 decimal place (for example 123,23 €)
 
3. If the user enters 123,00 it should automatically turn into 123 €.

Like I said I m a newbie in this area but eager to learn, so your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: there are many libraries http://numeraljs.com/ ,http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/ etc that can handle currency format

Answer (score 1):

A JS solution to this is to use `string.toLocaleString`. (From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```
var number = 123456.789;

// request a currency format
console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'}));
// → 123.456,79 €
```

Instead of "de-DE" you'll probably want to use your own country code.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is unnecessary in this case. Because you are using Acrobat, you can simply set the format on the field to be what you want. See image below.

[image]

Comment: Not quite @joelgeraci, I ll try to explain by an example. The desired format is that prices will be displayed without decimals when they don´t have them (for example 123 €) even if the user types in 123,00 €. But it also needs to be possible to display decimals when necessary (for example 123,23 €). With the settings shown above there will always be decimals, even if the input is only 123 (-->123,00 €).